# FORTRAN parsing file with varying line formate

Tags: fortran

I have only limited experience with FORTRAN and I need to parse files with a structure similar to this:

```
H    s         13.010000     0.019685
                1.962000     0.137977
                0.444600     0.478148

     s          0.122000     1.000000

     p          0.727000     1.000000
***
He   s         38.360000     0.023809
                5.770000     0.154891
                1.240000     0.469987

     s          0.297600     1.000000

     p          1.275000     1.000000
***
```

I need to search for the label (e.g. `He`) and then read the corresponding blocks into an array.

I know I can parse file by specifying the format each line is supposed to have, but here there are different formats possible.
In Python I would just split each line by the white spaces and deal with it depending on the number of columns. But how to approach this in FORTRAN?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I tried nothing, because I don't know yet what strategy to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read each line as a character string and then process it.  If, as it seems, the format is fixed (element symbol in first two characters, orbital letter in sixth character, etc.), the following program could serve you as inspiration:

```
program elms

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: MAX_LEN = 40
  character(len=MAX_LEN) :: line_el, line
  integer :: u
  integer :: is
  integer :: nlin
  character(len=2) :: element = 'He'

  integer, parameter :: MAX_LINES = 20
  real, dimension(MAX_LINES) :: e, f

  open(newunit=u, file='elms.dat', status='old', action='read')

  main_loop: do

     ! Read line
     read(u, '(a)', iostat=is) line_el

     if (eof_iostat(is)) exit main_loop

     ! Check first two characters of the line vs. chemical element.
     if (line_el(1:2) .eq. element) then

       ! This is the beginning of an element block
       nlin = 0
       line = line_el

       do

          if (line .ne. '') then
             ! Line is not empty or only spaces.

             nlin = nlin + 1

             if (line(6:6) .ne. ' ') then
                ! Line contains an orbital letter - process it.
             end if

             ! Read the real values in the rest of the line
             read(line(7:),*) e(nlin), f(nlin)

          end if

          ! Read next line
          read(u, '(a)', iostat=is) line

          if (eof_iostat(is)) exit main_loop

          if (line(1:2) .ne. '  ') then

             ! Finished processing element block.
             exit main_loop

          end if

       end do

     end if

  end do main_loop

  ! Close file
  close(u)

contains

  logical function eof_iostat(istat)

     ! Returns true if the end of file has been reached

     use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IOSTAT_END
     implicit none
     integer, intent(in) :: istat

     select case (istat)
        case (0)          ! No error
           eof_iostat = .false.
        case (IOSTAT_END) ! End of file reached
           eof_iostat = .true.
        case default      ! Error
           STOP
     end select

  end function eof_iostat

end program
```

You will probably need to make the program a subroutine, make `element` an `intent(in)` dummy argument, process the orbital symbols, etc.

Note that, if possible, it would be easier to just read all the data from the file in one go, and then search for the relevant data in the memory (e.g., having an array with the chemical symbols).

Comment: A bit overkill since I was only looking for the strategy to follow, not a complete program. But very useful.